# Get the sum of all Hashmap index sizes

Tags: android, hashmap

I am implementing a logic in which I have to multiply some integer with the size of the hashmap values in it. unfortunately, I am unable to do that. The attached picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arJM6.png) can provide me with all the size of the indexes. Now I want to sum all the sizes i.e. 0+2+1+1 and then multiply with my other integer. Is it possible? please help as I have no experience of hash mapping

***EDIT: the size that is written on top i.e. 4 is not what i required. This size is basically the size of how many indexes are there which are 4. However i want the sum of below sizes i.e. if there are 4 values inside index 2 then the total sum would be 6***

Comment: As it is, this question is quite confusing. You should take your specific problem and try to convert it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following snipet

```
int numberToMultiply = 0;
int total = 0;
for (String key : map.keySet()) {
   total = total + map.get(key).size()
}
 int ans = total*numberToMultiply
```

Answer (score 2):

Extract the values from your HasMap stringListMap.

```
for (String k : values.keySet())
{
   // this will get you the size i.e. 0, 2, 1 which is the element of 
   // stringListMap HashMap, use it the way you want.
    values.get(k);
}
```